# View incremental diffs of my revisions to files using Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, comparison, version-control, diff

Sometimes I use a simple editor like Notepad++ to edit my webpages on Dropbox.

Notepad++, not being an über-editor or IDE, does not track file changes for me.

But Dropbox does!!

Has anybody written a tool that is able to quickly view version history for a particular file in Dropbox? After all, saving to Dropbox is *essentially* like doing a `commit` to VCS.

Does anybody know if Dropbox exposes any API for querying past versions of a file?

Comment: very good idea, I think someone should work on this :D

Comment: Similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/641561/is-there-a-diff-tool-for-dropbox-for-mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Revisions](https://www.revisionsapp.com/) is an OS X option which has a specialized interface to facilitate browsing revisions.

I found this after I posted the original question, and it does a great job satisfying my requirement of *quickly* finding items. I wanted to avoid using the Dropbox web interface for that purpose.

No i am not trying to plug the product (come on, it's free!) I'm just writing this to report that I found what I was looking for in this product and that it solves my problem.

It solves my problem by giving me everything I could have wished for. It clearly uses the API which was mentioned in the previously accepted answer, and does all of the heavy lifting for you so that you can take a peek at your dropbox file content history, and then get on with the rest of your life.

The one downside is that I cannot use it from my Windows PC, I have to pull out my Macbook.

Comment: Please exercise caution when recommending software. As written, your answer may be seen as spam. Your answer should include a description of the software and how it addresses the question. More information: [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the current provided [REST API of Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#revisions)

Comment: This is nice. I envision a web-service that can provide a quick visual incremental diff interface. Sucks that you can't see *all* history without paying extra though (but that's understandable)

Comment: @StevenLu: Don't forget to mark right answer ;)

Comment: My *real* question is, who's already made a tool that does what I want? I suspect the answer is nobody (or the future me) but I'm gonna wait a bit longer. :)

Comment: @StevenLu: Are you still waiting? I am also looking for such service or would like to participate in its development.

Comment: @ps_ttf did you see my answer? Revisions works (if you are on OS X) and has great UX. Pretty sure it uses this very API.

Comment: @StevenLu: Sorry, I didn't noticed that answer. It's a pity that answer too few points.

Answer (score 4):

There is also [DropboxDiff](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dropboxdiff/aefdkgcdokdiaoppobphjogcilaaakka) by [Victor Shih](http://blog.vicshih.com/2011/09/dropboxdiff-chrome-extension.html).

Comment: [DropboxDiff](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dropboxdiff/aefdkgcdokdiaoppobphjogcilaaakka) really solved the problem for Windows users. But recently it stopped working! Chrome says "NPAPI plugin is required by this app".