# is there a Diff tool for dropbox for Mac?

Tags: mac, dropbox, diff

Is there a dropbox diff tool/app for Mac?

So what I mean here in an app that highlights visually the difference between versions in a text file you have on dropbox.  It would typically have two vertical panels with the documents you are comparing on either side.  When you scroll both scroll at the same time.  The differences are highlighted.

You would then click the dropbox versions you want to compare, for the dropbox file you selected, and scroll through the differences.

Comment: Similar question: http://superuser.com/questions/421812/view-incremental-diffs-of-my-revisions-to-files-using-dropbox

Answer (score 1):

There is an in-browser Chrome extension, [DropboxDiff](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dropboxdiff/aefdkgcdokdiaoppobphjogcilaaakka).  Here is the description:

> **DropboxDiff** *offered by Victor Shih*
>
> Compare versions of your Dropbox files in-browser or with your
>   configured diff tool. Trigger from any "Previous versions" page.
>   Provides two options for comparing different versions of your Dropbox
>   files:  1) a side-by-side diff within your browser, or 2) an external
>   diff tool.  This can be TortoiseMerge, kdiff3, FileMerge, or any tool
>   which can be triggered from a command line.
>
> In the "Previous versions" view of the Dropbox web interface of any
>   file, a column is added which allows you to select two versions to
>   compare.  Click the Inline button to view the difference in-browser,
>   or the Diff button to trigger your configured diff tool.
>
> Supports Windows, Mac, and Linux as far as I know, though I can't be
>   sure every possible configuration is covered.

Comment: DropboxDiff has stopped working for me (since some time 205). Now I would get an error: "DropboxDiff failed with

undefined

The JavaScript console of DropboxDiff's "background.html" page may have more information." Is there any new tools that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FileMerge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Developer_Tools#FileMerge). It is a free tool provided as part of Xcode. It provides an interface very similar to what you are describing. You can find it under the /Developer/Applications/Utilities/ (as of this posting) once XCode is installed.

Comment: Dropbox automatically versions files you save on it.  (You can see the versions in the web interface.)  It would be nice if there were a tool which could automatically retrieve the previous versions and compare them.  FileMerge would require you download both versions.

Comment: agreed Alan - what I'm really asking for here is something that automatically connects into dropbox - there are heaps of diff tools themselves otherwise